# How to adapt the quantity of items to display to viewport's width on Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a template that displays a certain quantity of items like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items.slice(0, 10)" :key="item" />
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I show less items on mobile viewport, modifying my slice function ?

I would like to avoid duplicating code and having two lists, one with `items.slice(0, 10)` and one with `items.slice(0, 5)`, and show one or the other according to a media query because that's not scalable.

I thought about checking user's viewport width on `mounted` and on page-resize and update the quantity of items that are displayed according to this but I don't find it very clean.

I feel like it's a very common use-case though, is there a good way of doing this ?

Comment: Can you add a CSS classname to all items you want to hide on mobile and then use media-queries to hide them? Don't know if that is a clean way to fix.

Comment: @Luckyfella that will still load the data (even if they are hidden, they are still present in the DOM).

Comment: As @kissu says it will still be present in the DOM, and if instead of having a div on that v-for I iterate over a custom component with some logic inside, all these components will be initiated, that's not good for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always found that way pretty clunky: using JS for this matter while this is more of a CSS/lazy-loading thing.

I guess you can use this package: https://github.com/scaccogatto/vue-viewports.
By using something like this

```html
<div v-for="item in items.slice(0, this.$currentViewport.label === 'mobile' ? 5 : 10)"
  :key="item"
/>
```

Inspired by this approach I guess: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/

Comment: Although it adds a dependency it's true it looks clean. I don't think it's more a CSS thing, I don't want to hide additional items visually only but not even add them to the DOM, so I guess adapting the `v-for` is the only way of doing it

Comment: @hnrd you can always use this composable (1kB): https://vueuse.org/core/usebreakpoints/#usebreakpoints if you want something more official/battle-tested by the Vue team.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a computed flag to determine the screen width seems a better solution.
You can try like this:

```js
created() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth
  })
},
computed: {
 isMobile() {
    if (this.screenWidth <= 760) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  },
  myItems() {
    return (this.isMobile) ? this.items.slice(0,5) : this.items.slice(0,10)
  }
}
```

Now you can use the flag anywhere to decide your array lengths on different screen widths.

Comment: This approach is similar to what I say when I talk about checking the viewport width on mounted and on resize and adjust the quantity of items according to it. For now that's the best way I can imagine of achieving it though