# Vue Determining class based on screen size widths

Tags: vue.js

i'm making a project with vue, but the thing i'm stuck on is,
v-bind class `type` if `vertical-navigation-mode-side`
Add the `open` class to the header class, of course, the `mobileMode` value will also be checked.
same way
If the v-bind class is `type` `vertical-navigation-mode-over`, the `open` class in the header class will be searched and deleted for (responsive) in the first place.

exactly what I want to do is available in the image below

[image]
APP.VUE

```html
<template>
  <header class="dark" :class="type">Menu</header>
  <section class="flex">
    <TopHeader/>
    <div class="flex">
      <RouterView/>
    </div>
    <Footer/>
  </section>
</template>
<script setup>
import TopHeader from "./layouts/TopHeader.vue";
import Footer from "./layouts/Footer.vue";
import {computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, provide, ref} from "vue";

const mobileMode = ref(false)
provide('mobileMode', mobileMode)

function useBreakpoints() {
  let windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth)

  const onWidthChange = () => windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))

  const type = computed(() => {
    if (windowWidth.value < 550) return 'mode-over'
    if (windowWidth.value >= 550 && windowWidth.value < 1200) return 'mode-over'
    if (windowWidth.value >= 1200) return 'mode-side'
    return null; 
  })
  const width = computed(() => windowWidth.value)
  return {width, type}
}

const {width, type} = useBreakpoints()
</script>
```

TOPHEADER.VUE

```html
<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <button @click="handleStatus">MODE</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {inject} from "vue";
const mobileMode = inject('mobileMode');
const handleStatus = () => mobileMode.value = !mobileMode.value
</script>
```

FOOTER.VUE

```html
<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <span class="font-medium text-secondary">FOOTER</span>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-overlay" v-if="showMenu===true" @click="handleStatus"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {inject} from "vue";

const showMenu = inject('showMenu');
const handleStatus = () => showMenu.value = false
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I've already saw that one yesterday. Why did you deleted/created a new one?

Comment: Why not using css media-queries ? it's not resolving your problem but it maybe the best for you as you only use `type` for a class name

Comment: I want to do it as javascript

Comment: You can give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74234391/8816585

Comment: Could you please write in more detail.

Comment: What do you not understand? Vuetify's approach regarding breaking points or the Vueuse helper? The discussion is giving you 2 approaches to solve your challenge or trying to tracks viewport's size.

Comment: Firstly I don't use vuetify and secondly you are not helping

Comment: I was just referring a possible approach, that you could get some inspiration by checking Vuetify's source code. The Vueuse helper is still relevant. Sorry if I cannot help further, but the question is also quite bulky in terms of details. Good luck for the rest.

Comment: I'm so new I thought you can help me, how can I do something right now